# MongoDB - How to filter results of an lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm new to MongoDB.

My lookup gives me the following result, how can I filter through the results below in order to get `expected_delivery_time`, using MongoDB aggregate:

```
[
   {
      "from":"Jeddah",
      "delivery_rule":[
         {
            "to":"Makkah",
            "expected_delivery_time":3
         },
         {
            "to":"Riyadh",
            "expected_delivery_time":2
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "from":"Riyadh",
      "delivery_rule":[
         {
            "to":"Makkah",
            "expected_delivery_time":3
         },
         {
            "to":"Riyadh",
            "expected_delivery_time":1
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Below is my code:

```
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "Setting",
        pipeline: [
        {
            $match: {
                $expr: {
                    { $eq: ["$name", "delivery_rules"] }
                }
            }
        ],
        as: "delivery_rules"
    }
},
{ "$match": { "$delivery_rules.value.from": "Jeddah" } },
{ "$match": { "$delivery_rules.value.to": "Riyadh" } },
```

I need help with below MySQL equivalent to:

```
SELECT 'expected_delivery_time' WHERE from='Jeddah' AND to='Makkah'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `$lookup` stage, I expected the result documents should be:

```
[
  {
    "from": "Jeddah",
    "delivery_rules": [
      {
        "to": "Makkah",
        "expected_delivery_time": 3
      },
      {
        "to": "Riyadh",
        "expected_delivery_time": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "from": "Riyadh",
    "delivery_rules": [
      {
        "to": "Makkah",
        "expected_delivery_time": 3
      },
      {
        "to": "Riyadh",
        "expected_delivery_time": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

`delivery_rules` (with "s", but the document you shared is with `delivery_rule`)

Both `delivery_rules.value.from` and `delivery_rules.value.to` don't exist. And you shouldn't use `$` for the field in `$match` stage based on your query.

1. `$lookup`
2. `$match` - Filter `from` and `delivery_rules.to`. Combine 2 `$match` stages into 1.
3. `$project` - Decorate output document. Add `expected_delivery_time` field:

   3.1. `$getField` - Get `expected_delivery_time` field from the result *3.1.1.*

   3.1.1. `$first` - Get the first value from the result *3.1.1.1* array.

   3.1.1.1. `$filter` - Filter the document with `to` is "Makkah" in `delivery_rules` array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /* Lookup stage */
  {
    "$match": {
      "from": "Jeddah",
      "delivery_rules.to": "Riyadh"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      expected_delivery_time: {
        "$getField": {
          "field": "expected_delivery_time",
          "input": {
            $first: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$delivery_rules",
                cond: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$this.to",
                    "Makkah"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VPQ3CBKw-r1)